# Warning: [object Object]: `ref` is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in `undefined` being returned

Tags: reactjs

**What should happen:** Close the modal when you click outside of the modal box when it is open.

**Problem:** The box does not closed and I get this error:

`Warning: [object Object]: 'ref' is not a prop. Trying to access it will result in 'undefined' being returned. If you need to access the same value within the child component, you should pass it as a different prop.`

My log in this code (clicking outside 1) when I click outside of the modal box prints the following:

`clicking outside 1 | e:[object HTMLDivElement] | ref: {current: null}`

**Modal.js**

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { ModalBody } from "src/components/core/modal/components/modal-body";
import { ModalInner } from "src/components/core/modal/components/modal-inner";
import { ModalOuter } from "src/components/core/modal/components/modal-outer";
import styles from "src/components/core/modal/styles.module.css";
import { HR } from "src/components/ui/hr";
import { Layout } from "src/components/ui/layout";
import { createRef } from "react";

function useOutsideAlerter(ref) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ref:", ref);
    function handleClickOutside(event) {
      console.log("clicking outside 1 | e:" + event.target + " | ref:", ref);
      if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
        console.log("clicking outside 2");
        props.handleClose();
      }
    }

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleClickOutside);
    };
  }, [ref]);
}

export const Modal = (props) => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useOutsideAlerter(ref);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <ModalOuter
        showModal={props.showModal}
        id={styles["modalOuter"]}
        handleClose={props.handleClose}
      >
        <ModalInner
          ref={ref}
          handleClose={props.handleClose}
          modalType={props.modalType}
        >
          <Layout display="flex" flexDirection="column" width="100%">
            <Layout display="flex" flexDirection="column">
              <ModalBody body={props.body} title={props.title} />
            </Layout>
          </Layout>
        </ModalInner>
      </ModalOuter>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

**ModalInner**

```
import "src/components/core/modal/styles.module.css";
import { Layout } from "src/components/ui/layout";
import { Color } from "src/properties/color.js";
import { getBreakpoint } from "src/utilities/get-breakpoint";
import { Breakpoints } from "src/properties/breakpoints";
import { forwardRef } from "react";

const ImageModal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Layout
      id={props.id}
      ref={ref}
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      borderRadius="5px"
      margin="2rem"
      padding="2rem"
      // transform="translate(-50%, -50%)"
      // backgroundColor="black"
      border={`1px solid ${Color.Black}`}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Layout>
  );
});

const BasicModal = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <Layout
      id={props.id}
      ref={ref}
      display="flex"
      justifyContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      padding="2rem"
      margin="2rem"
      borderRadius="5px"
      // transform="translate(-50%, -50%)"
      backgroundColor="white"
      border={`1px solid ${Color.LightGray}`}
      boxShadow={`0rem 0rem .3rem white`}
    >
      {props.children}
    </Layout>
  );
});

export const ModalInner = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const breakpoint = getBreakpoint();
  const isMobile = breakpoint == Breakpoints.Mobile;

  const modalType = props.modalType || "basic";

  if (modalType == "image") {
    return <ImageModal ref={ref} {...props} />;
  } else {
    return <BasicModal ref={ref} {...props} />;
  }
});
```

Layout.js

```
import { forwardRef } from "react";

export const Layout = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  return (
    <>
      <div
        className={props.className}
        data-tip={props.dataTip}
        hidden={props.hidden}
        id={props.id}
        onClick={props.onClick}
        onScroll={props.onScroll}
        onFocus={props.onFocus}
        onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
        onBlur={props.onBlur}
        ref={props.ref}
        tabIndex={props.tabIndex}
        target={props.target}
        style={{
          alignItems: props.alignItems,
          background: props.background,
          backgroundImage: props.backgroundImage,
          backgroundRepeat: props.backgroundRepeat,
          backgroundSize: props.backgroundSize,
          backgroundColor: props.backgroundColor,
          backgroundPosition: props.backgroundPosition,
          backgroundAttachment: props.backgroundAttachment,
          border: props.border,
          borderTop: props.borderTop,
          borderRight: props.borderRight,
          borderBottom: props.borderBottom,
          borderLeft: props.borderLeft,
          borderRadius: props.borderRadius,
          boxShadow: props.boxShadow,
          cursor: props.cursor,
          display: props.display,
          flex: props.flex,
          flexDirection: props.flexDirection,
          flexWrap: props.flexWrap,
          flexShrink: props.flexShrink,
          gridTemplateColumns: props.gridTemplateColumns,
          height: props.height,
          justifyContent: props.justifyContent,
          maxHeight: props.maxHeight,
          maxWidth: props.maxWidth,
          minHeight: props.minHeight,
          minWidth: props.minWidth,
          objectFit: props.objectFit,
          opacity: props.opacity,
          overflow: props.overflow,
          overflowX: props.overflowX,
          overflowY: props.overflowY,
          pointerEvents: props.pointerEvents,
          position: props.position,
          width: props.width,
          top: props.top,
          left: props.left,
          right: props.right,
          bottom: props.bottom,
          transform: props.transform,
          whiteSpace: props.whiteSpace,
          zIndex: props.zIndex,

          margin: props.margin,
          padding: props.padding,
          ...(props.style || {}),
        }}
      >
        {props.children}
      </div>
    </>
  );
});
```

What am I missing to be able to close the modal by clicking outside of ModalInner?

Comment: Could you share your `Layout` component code as well?

Comment: Edited question to include it.

Comment: The `ref={props.ref}` in Layout.js might better be `ref={ref}`

Comment: As soon as @juliomalves asked for the layout component, I knew this was going to be it. The error never led me to this component. Thanks heroes. You can add the answer and I'll accept it.